# Apache Spark installation with Java Error

Tags: java, apache-spark

Hi I am having a problem to install spark on my PC having the Java error below.
Would you help me and give me tips how to fix it?

Thanks millions in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuTnD.png)

Comment: Would be better if you put the text of your error in your post rather than an external link. If you’d do that as a more seasoned SO users, you would probably be sacked.

Comment: Add to your post: version of Java, version of Scala, version of Spark, version of windows, what have you done/tried so far…

Comment: Hi jgp  thank you for your advice. java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)  Windows 11/ spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2

Comment: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$ (in unnamed module @0x6f27a732) cannot access class sun.nio.ch.DirectBuffer (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.nio.ch to unnamed module @0x6f27a732

Comment: <console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^

Comment: Do not add comments, modify your questions so there is a synthetic view of your isssues. Basically, don’t answer my questions, create a better question…

Comment: Hi jgp  I have tried out with Java 8 and spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7 and it worked !!

Comment: Thanks for confirming! Now, you have to upvote my answer and say it’s the right answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(See my comments above, but here is my answer)

As Spark relies on Scala (but you don’t have to use Scala yourself) you are dependent on the **version** of the JVM used by Scala, which in your situation is Java 8 or 11, not 17.

Check out https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ for more details.

Install Java 8 or 11, point your JAVA_HOME to the right directory, and run Spark again.

Comment: jgp helped me with a right answer ! thank you